# How to make our app run in all the screen sizes without getting our components collapsed and mergen into each other?

Tags: android

I made a single activity app with a picture and a text box and a get started button.Picture isl located at the center,text box just beneath it and button at bottom right corner..but when I run the app the picture and the text box are overlapping each other...and the button is located at the bottom center ......so how to make sure that this doesn't happen.

Comment: share your code please

Comment: Use different layouts for different screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

create dimens in dimens.xml folder for different screen size .
like dimen.xml(sw560dp). and define size for different widgets in different dimens.

Answer (score 0):

Few things you must keep in mind while making screens compatible to multiple screen sizes.

1. Use dp instead of px in your dimensions.
2. Use proper layout management. That is use linear layout wherever possible.
3. Images should have 5 copies for mpdi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, and xxxhdpi.

For further details visit this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html)